# Calculate with content of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I'm a complete n00b in JS / JQuery, so be a bit gentle ;-)
I'd like to change the content of a span with class: score.
Better said: calculate with it. It's an average score, what should be doubled.
The score is based on a star-rating (which has a max of 5) but I'd like to bend it to get a relevant score which lays between 1 and 10. In my opinion it's just multiplying this amount with 2.

Let's say that the average score is 4.6. In that case we can change the scale of the score to 10, thus multiplying with 2 would give the same result, but on a different scale, right? 4.6 == 9.2.

This is the code I have:

```
<span class="score">4.6</span>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function compute() {
    var oldscore = $( ".score" ).text;
    var multiplier = 2;
    var total = oldscore * multiplier;
    $( ".score" ).text(total);
}

$('.score').change(compute);
});

</script>
```

Big chance that I've built it in a very wrong way :-D
I'd be very happy if someone could put me in the right direction :-)

Comment: How you are setting the value inside the span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<span class="score">4.6</span>
<script>
function compute() {
    var oldscore = $( ".score" ).text();
    var multiplier = 2;
    var total = parseFloat(oldscore) * parseFloat(multiplier);
    $( ".score" ).text(total);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  compute();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can also create function compute() in $(document).ready()

Comment: You saved my day @Websmartiz IT Solution! I placed the $(document).ready function before the actual 'happening' as you said! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
I needed to add some time-out to the script. This solved everything!

Does is matter that in the Live situation, there are 2 classes assigned to the span?
Because in the Live situation, it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function compute() {
    var oldscore = $( ".avg-score .font-color-gray-darker" ).text();
    var multiplier = 2;
    var total = parseFloat(oldscore) * parseFloat(multiplier);
    $( ".avg-score .font-color-gray-darker" ).text(total);
});
```

You could see it live here:
https://testing.sceneryworkshop.com/paints-module-26mm-om05s-105478183.html

(on the bottom)

Comment: P.s. I started trying with a single class: .avg-score, but that didn't work also